# Resource with chess problems in electronic format with solutions

Tags: problems

I am looking for a database of [chess problems](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/2145/703) in electronic format with solutions. Ideal variant will be a database with something like:

- FEN starting position *
- description (Mate in 3 moves, Win material, Black to draw)
- solution *
- strength of the problem

Only * are really needed, other things just nice to have. It does not matter whether the resource is free or paid. Of course I can get some books and extract such positions by myself, but I hope that someone already have done something like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for tactical puzzles, there is always CT-Art from Convecta. You can also try Tactic Trainer for Android. It has a nifty difficulty rating system.

Also there is an online resource I forgot to add : http://www.yacpdb.org/

Comment: Looks good, do you have any idea whether it is possible to reuse their puzzles?

Comment: You are allowed to use a game of Carlsen for mass distribution, without any copyright infringement. I think thay you can do the same with their puzzles, but not with the software. I am not 100% sure though. You should read ther terms, which no one ever does.

Answer (score 1):

I really like [ChessTempo](http://chesstempo.com) for tactics training. Not sure if there is an option to download problems though.